Problem between KMP and Room DB: Cannot find implementation for org.asinfo.mobiletest.database.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
I am working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project using the Rooom library. The project does not share UI code. When I run the project for the Android platform, I am getting the next error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application org.asinfo.mobiletest.PlaygroundApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for org.asinfo.mobiletest.database.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist. Is Room annotation processor correctly configured?
I am using the configuration setup given by the official docs: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/multiplatform/room. In the shared module, per each platform, I have created the getDatabaseBuilder() function. But, when I call it from the compose module, I get that error.
The code from shared/src/androidMain:
fun getDatabaseBuilder(ctx: Context): RoomDatabase.Builder<AppDatabase> {
    val appContext = ctx.applicationContext
    val dbFile = appContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME)

    return Room.databaseBuilder<AppDatabase>(
        context = appContext,
        name = dbFile.absolutePath
    )
}

I am passing the context calling this function from a class that extends Application().
I think it's a problem related to the modules, because, I test the same with a project that shares all the UI code (therefore, you have all the code inside one module) and I did not get any errors.
